# Сказал  ()  как отрезал

Tags: пунктуация, фразеология, как, сравнительный-оборот

Обычно фразеологизмы с союзом КАК не обособляются: Блестит как зеркало, белый как снег. Но при этом они относятся к глаголу или прилагательному и являются обстоятельствами образа действия или степени.

А как быть с фразеологизмом «сказал как отрезал»? Здесь тоже оборот в роли обстоятельства, но повторяется форма глагола, да и интонация разная: произношение возможно то с паузой, то без паузы.

В примерах приводятся цитаты из произведений одного автора (Б. Васильева) с разным оформлением:

(1) Сказал ― как отрезал. И сомнения не осталось: утопит.

(2) Гвоздин уже увел хоперцев, а командир уманцев войсковой старшина Кванин сказал как отрезал:

(3)― Нет, ― сказал, как отрезал: коротко, жестко и сурово.

И еще интересно: есть ли еще фразеологизмы с союзом КАК и повтором глаголов? Или еще: есть ли примеры с повтором глагола, но не фразеологического характера, чтобы запятую можно было поставить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая не ставится перед подчинительным союзом или союзным словом в составе неразложимых сочетаний, например: делай что хочешь, живите как знаете.

Думаю, что выражение СКАЗАЛ КАК ОТРЕЗАЛ подчиняется этому правилу, но возможны авторские варианты его пунктуационного оформления в контексте разных предложений из-за бесспорной экспрессивности этой фразы.

Фразеологизмов с глаголами одинаковой формы и союзом "как" между ними не  припомнила, но пунктуация в выражениях типа "посмотрела как погладила", "взглянул как попрощался" действительно вызывает интерес. Спасибо за вопрос.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы, честно говоря, тут вообще не ставила знака препинания. Все-таки "сказал как отрезал" - это устойчивый оборот, вроде "спать как сурок" и т.д. А в приведенных Вами примерах, видимо, авторские знаки, которыми те хотели подчеркнуть интонацию.

Comment: Меня смущает как раз интонация, да и в Нацкорпусе  разные варианты встречаются одинаково часто и у разных авторов.